# dataExporter cannot be rendered because of form needing

Tags: pdf, primefaces, data-export

I am trying to add dataExporter component to my table. 
First I had **{Exporters}** beside pagination facet , then after a lot of tries I got this error in the console

> HTML nesting warning on closing changes: element update not explicitly closed

I solved it also but now there is nothing appears in the Exporter facet. I googled it and found that I need a form in my page because of this commandlink submit a form , so it needs a form.

My Question here is how to apply [this example](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataexporter/basic.xhtml) in my project.

Here is my code.

```
<ui:composition template="/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="title">
        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ViewLfmTitle}"></h:outputText>
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="body">
        <h:panelGroup id="messagePanel" layout="block">
            <h:messages errorStyle="color: red" infoStyle="color: green"
                        layout="table" />
        </h:panelGroup>
        <p:dialog header="Add Task" widgetVar="dlg" position="center center"
                  onShow="PF('dlg').initPosition()" modal="true" closeOnEscape="true"
                  resizable="false">
            <h:form>

                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateTaskLabel_name}" for="name" />
                    <p:inputText id="name"
                                 value="#{ViewLfmJpaController.newTaskDTO.name}"
                                 title="#{bundle.CreateTaskTitle_name}" />
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateTaskLabel_durationPerMonth}"
                                   for="durationPerMonth" />
                    <p:inputText id="durationPerMonth"
                                 value="#{ViewLfmJpaController.newTaskDTO.duration}"
                                 title="#{bundle.CreateTaskTitle_durationPerMonth}" />
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateTaskLabel_startDate}"
                                   for="startDate" />
                    <p:calendar id="startDate"
                                value="#{ViewLfmJpaController.newTaskDTO.startDate}"
                                title="#{bundle.CreateTaskTitle_startDate}" pattern="d MMM yyyy"
                                effect="fold">
                        <f:convertDateTime pattern="d MMM yyyy" />
                    </p:calendar>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateTaskLabel_endDate}"
                                   for="endDate" />
                    <p:calendar id="endDate"
                                value="#{ViewLfmJpaController.newTaskDTO.endDate}"
                                title="#{bundle.CreateTaskTitle_endDate}" pattern="d MMM yyyy"
                                effect="fold">
                        <f:convertDateTime pattern="d MMM yyyy" />
                    </p:calendar>
                    <f:facet name="footer">

                        <p:commandButton value="Add"
                                         actionListener="#{ViewLfmJpaController.addTask}" update="Matrix"
                                         oncomplete="PF('dlg').hide()" />
                    </f:facet>


                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
        </p:dialog>

        <p:dataTable id="Matrix" resizableColumns="true" scrollable="true"
                     scrollHeight="80%"
                     value="#{ViewLfmJpaController.selected.tasksDtoCollection}"
                     paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {Exporters}"
                     var="item" resizeMode="expand" paginator="true" rows="10"
                     style="margin-bottom:20px">
            <f:facet name="header">
                Logical Framewrok Matrix
            </f:facet>

            <f:facet name="{Exporters}">
                <p:commandLink>
                    <p:graphicImage name="../resources/images/pdf.jpg" width="24" />
                    <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="Matrix" fileName="lfm" />
                </p:commandLink>
            </f:facet>
            <p:column headerText="Index" colspan="1">
                <c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="#{ViewLfmJpaController.listSize}">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{i}"></p:outputLabel>
                </c:forEach>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Task Title">
                <p:outputLabel value="#{item.name}"></p:outputLabel>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Start Date" colspan="3">
                <p:outputLabel value="#{item.formatedStartDate}"></p:outputLabel>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="End Date" colspan="3">
                <p:outputLabel value="#{item.formatedEndDate}"></p:outputLabel>
            </p:column>
            <c:forEach var="i" begin="1"
                       end="#{ViewLfmJpaController.numberOfMonths}">
                <p:column headerText="m ${i}" colspan="1"></p:column>
            </c:forEach>
            <p:column headerText="Exptected Outcomes" colspan="4">
                <ui:repeat value="#{item.tasksExpectedOutcomesCollection}" var="teo">
                    <li><h:outputText value="#{teo.expectation}">


                        </h:outputText></li>
                </ui:repeat>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>

        <p:commandButton value="Add Task" oncomplete="PF('dlg').show()"></p:commandButton>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: It's not clear why you tagged iText, because there is no iText related code in your question.

Comment: I googled for "primefaces" (never heard of it) and apparently it has an optional dependency on iText 2.1.7. Tough luck, that version is no longer supported by iText Software. But still, your question contains no iText code, only Primefaces xml. I am going to delete the iText tag from your question. You can re-add it if you edit your question and add code that uses the iText API.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]? I have a hard time distilling the real cause etc... @AmedeevanGasse: No tough luck... iText 2.1.7 works for the things it needs to do.

Comment: you are right @AmedeeVanGasse about iText library , but I want to make an exporter table and I cannot make it visible. Could anyone helps me.
Thak you in advance :) .

Comment: @kukeltje anyway, the question is not about iText, don't you agree?

Comment: Okay you are right ,

Comment: but now my error is **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lowagie.text.DocumentException**
could you help me in it

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse: correct, that is why I did not re-add it

Comment: What did you change? And please stop adding 'can anyone help', 'could you help' etc at the end of each comment...

Comment: I posted the answer , you can check it.

Answer (score 0):

I FOUND THE SOLUTION BY MYSELF.
First : You have to know that you cannot make nested forms in your page.
Second : you have to know that to submit  `<p:dialog> </p:dialog>` or to use   `<h:commandLink>  </h:commandLink>`  you need to use form.

So I had removed the form in the dialog component and add a general component contains `dialog` and `dataTable` together

Comment: ALWAYS, ALWAYS, ALWAYS post a [mcve]. The problem you had was not visible from the code you posted. So we were chasing 'ghosts'.

Comment: I understood that but I was not know where is my problem.

Comment: That is where a [mcve] helps... You start removing more and more until there is very little left and if you remove one additional thing it starts working...